# JS Log says TypeError undefined, whilst debug delivers value

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to write an interface to make the contract generation easier for our students club and have some features like a kinda cart where additional requests by the contractor can be added from a selectbox.

I get the values for the new row by data-* fields from the selectbox and somehow it receives the information but still gives an error
`TypeError: $items_key is undefined`
which I don't understand

I tried to catch the error with some typeof if-condition

```
$items_key = $items[$(this).find('option:selected').data('key')];

// tr data-row - identifier, data-slug - itemslug
// if empty/null/0, set integer 1, 0 ist always the empty one
$newrow.attr('data-row',($newrow.data('row') === 0) ? 1 : $newrow.data('row')+1 );
// set slug, !!ERROR HERE!!
$newrow.attr('data-slug',$items_key['slug']);

for (var $key in $items_key) {
    $newrow.find('[name="'+$key+'"]').val($items_key[$key]);
}
```

full page:https://manage.rotorkunstkultur.com/eacvertrag/

This codeblock works as expected, but I do not understand why it delivers the error

Comment: can you provide code of that ?

Comment: The link is working, I thought this might be best.... code is "too long"

Comment: so how we know where error gonna be happened and why ?

Comment: agree just worked out the code part, sorry

Comment: Is this code asynchronous in any way?

Comment: not afaik. its just a simple routine part of a jquery plugin bound to onclick.